# Icon change not showing using Redux Tool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a situation here where there are two components. the first component have an input field and the other component is displaying icon and a title name. i used Redux toolkit where when the input field is written anything the icon is changed to another icon. the problem is the icon doesn't change i don't why so, i want to know how to define the icon in the component as shown in my code below.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  icon: "unTick",
  value: "",
};

const tickSlice = createSlice({
  name: "tickSign",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
    changeIcon: (state) => {
      if (state.icon === "unTick") {
        state.icon = "tick";
      } else {
        state.icon = "unTick";
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { changeIcon, setValue } = tickSlice.actions;
export const selectValue = (state) => state.value;
export const selectIcon = (state) => state.icon;

export default tickSlice.reducer;
```

the code of the first component of input

```
  const value = useSelector(selectValue);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      dispatch(setValue(e.target.value));
      if (e.target.value.trim().length !== 0) {
        dispatch(changeIcon("tick"));
      } else {
        dispatch(changeIcon("unTick"));
      }
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
<input
            id="boxInput"
            type="text"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Enter Apprenticeship Title"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
```

the code for the icon change component

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectIcon } from "../features/TickSlice";
import { TickCircle, UnTickCircle } from "./IconSvg";

const DescNavTitles = ({ title }) => {
  const icon = useSelector(selectIcon);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className="navTitle">
      <svg>{icon === "tick" ? <TickCircle /> : <UnTickCircle />}</svg>
      <p className="navTitle__name">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DescNavTitles;
```

So, i don't know where exactly should i define the icon to be displayed and changed dynamically

[components on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QcxI.png)

[Redux tool when written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BM30.jpg)

[Redux tool when not written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ldFd.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting the `icon` state correctly. Based on the screen captures showing the Redux state from the devtools your root state has two properties, `appren` and `tick`.

The Redux state:

```js
{
  appren: {
    boxItems: [....],
    title: "",
    position: "",
    ...
  },
  tick: {
    icon: "....",
    value: "...."
  },
}
```

I'm assuming it's this `state.tick` that is the `tickSign` slice you are working with. Recall that the `useSelector` hook callback is passed the ***entire*** Redux state object.

```
const icon = useSelector(state => state.tick.icon);
```

The `selectValue` and `selectIcon` selector functions need to access the correct path to access the expected state properties.

```
export const selectValue = (state) => state.tick.value;
export const selectIcon = (state) => state.tick.icon;
```

Additionally, the `changeIcon` action is only toggling the state value when dispatched, but it seems you want to conditionally set the value from an `input` element's `onChange` handler. I suggest the following refactor:

```
const initialState = {
  isTicked: false,
  value: "",
};

const tickSlice = createSlice({
  name: "tickSign",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
    changeIsTicked: (state, action) => {
      state.isTicked = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { changeIcon, setValue } = tickSlice.actions;
export const selectValue = (state) => state.tick.value;
export const selectIsTicked = (state) => state.tick.isTicked;
```

```
const value = useSelector(selectValue);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
  dispatch(setValue(e.target.value));
  dispatch(changeIsTicked(e.target.value.trim().length !== 0));
}, [dispatch]);

<input
  id="boxInput"
  type="text"
  value={value}
  placeholder="Enter Apprenticeship Title"
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

```
const DescNavTitles = ({ title }) => {
  const isTicked = useSelector(selectIsTicked);

  return (
    <div className="navTitle">
      <svg>{isTicked ? <TickCircle /> : <UnTickCircle />}</svg>
      <p className="navTitle__name">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `isTicked` state is actually unnecessary though as it can be completely derived from the `state.tick.value` state value. You can create a selector function that computes this. Example:

```
const initialState = {
  value: "",
};

const tickSlice = createSlice({
  name: "tickSign",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setValue: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { changeIcon, setValue } = tickSlice.actions;
export const selectValue = (state) => state.tick.value;
export const selectIsTicked = (state) => !!state.tick.value.length;
```

```
const DescNavTitles = ({ title }) => {
  const isTicked = useSelector(selectIsTicked);

  return (
    <div className="navTitle">
      <svg>{selectIsTicked ? <TickCircle /> : <UnTickCircle />}</svg>
      <p className="navTitle__name">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```